# GitHub Action test julia submodules

Tags: julia, github-actions, cicd

I have a project with the following structure:

```
my_project
- .github\workflows
    - my_github_action.yml
- src
    - main.jl
    - Manifest.toml
    - Project.toml
    -my_sub_module1
        - Manifest.toml
        - Project.toml
        - src
            - some_code.jl
        - test
            - runtests.jl
            - my_tests.jl
    -my_sub_module2
        - Manifest.toml
        - Project.toml
        - src
            - some_code.jl
        - test
            - runtests.jl
            - my_tests.jl
```

And I would like to create an action GitHub testing each of my sub modules. I tried a lot of different possibilities, unfortunately, none of them is working. The idea would be to do something like following:

```
name: Run tests

on: 
    push:
        branches:
            - github_tests
    pull_request:
jobs:
    test:
        runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
        strategy:
            matrix:
                julia-version: ['1.9.2']
                julia-arch: [x64]
                os: [windows-latest]

        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - uses: julia-actions/setup-julia@v1
                with:
                    version: ${{ matrix.julia-version }}
            - name: Test package my_sub_module1
                run: julia --check-bounds=yes --color=yes -e 'import Pkg; Pkg.activate("src/my_sub_module1"); Pkg.test()'
            - name: Test package my_sub_module2
                run: julia --check-bounds=yes --color=yes -e 'import Pkg; Pkg.activate("src/my_sub_module2"); Pkg.test()'
```

Would you know how should I write my GitHub action?
Thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution.

First I introduced a folder test in my main project with a file runtests.jl as follow:

```
using Pkg

Pkg.test("my_sub_module1")
Pkg.test("my_sub_module2")
```

Then I updated my GitHub action with the following steps:

```
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: julia-actions/setup-julia@v1
        with:
          version: ${{ matrix.julia-version }}
          arch: ${{ matrix.julia-arch }}
      - uses: julia-actions/julia-buildpkg@v1
      - uses: julia-actions/julia-runtest@v1
```

I am not 100% convinced with this solution. For clarity reason, I would prefer to  split the test of each sub-module.